# JavaScript and geolocation

Tags: javascript, geolocation

)

So I'm trying to learn about JavaScript and geolocation, but I've run into this, probably simple, problem:

```
let myLat; // Global

navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
    myLat = position.coords.latitude;
    console.log(myLat); // works
});

console.log(myLat); // undefined
```

I don't get why I cannot just use a global variable to hold the latitude-info?

Comment: because `getCurrentPosition` is asynchronous

Comment: `getCurrentPosition` is an async process. JS will put it on the task queue, and then process the next statement. `myLat` doesn't exist until the the process has been resolved which is why the first log works, but the second doesn't.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call